# PDF.JS in Xamarin Forms -> Pinch to Zoom?

Tags: javascript, c#, xamarin, smartphone

I have the pdf.js-Plugin in my Xamarin-Forms Project.
But pdf-js dont support the touch events (long press for mark, double tap for zoomin/out, pinch to zoom ...).

I look @stackoverflow, but i dont find any correct solution.

1. Attempt to install hammer.js - Failed
2. Use the "HandTool" from pdf.js - Failed
3. build with javascript hand-tool - failed

Comment: If you want to open pdf file in Xamarin.forms ,check https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/showing-pdf-files-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Hey, open File ist correct, the pdf.js viewer show the file. My problem, there cant use touch events.

Comment: Provide the full code or sample so that I can test it on my side.

Comment: You need the pdf-js Download (https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download) stable. And my code for Xamarin (https://dotnetfiddle.net/YETlmg)

Comment: Post your code in this case.